# JQuery ul li click move to next five elements in list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following list of examples:

```
<div class="data-box">
        <div class="prev-next"><a href="">Prev <i class="uparrow-icon"></i></a></div>
        <ul class="hours-list">

                <li class="extra-hour"> 4:45 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 5:23 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 6:00 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 6:19 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 6:37 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 6:55 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 7:12 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 7:28 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 7:44 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 8:00 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 8:16 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 8:33 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 8:50 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 9:08 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 9:27 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 9:47 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 10:07 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 10:27 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 10:47 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 11:07 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 11:27 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 11:47 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 12:07 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 12:27 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 12:47 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 13:07 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 13:27 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 13:47 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 14:08 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 14:30 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 14:53 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 15:15 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 15:36 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 15:56 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 16:16 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 16:36 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 16:56 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 17:16 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 17:36 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 17:56 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 18:21 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 18:46 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 19:11 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 19:36 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 20:01 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 20:26 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 20:51 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 21:16 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 21:42 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 22:08 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>

                <li class="extra-hour"> 22:35 h. <i class="plus-icon"></i></li>



        </ul> 
        <div class="prev-next"><a href="">Next <i class="downarrow-icon"></i></a></div>
    </div>
```

I wish when I press prev and next, respectively go to the next or previous five elements. All other elements are hidden and not visible. How can you do that with JQuery ?

Early show set li, but for this example let's all hidden. Then press next and should appear next 5 items from the list and hide the current 5, this is done for example with slidetoggle or something. When pressed prev do show the previous 5 and hide the rest.

Comment: Have you tried something so far?

Comment: You mean you have multiple .prev-next in html? All hidden and clicking on one should show the next 5th .prev-next? Your question is not clear enough .

Comment: So far I have not tried anything with Jquery

Comment: @Krasimir take a look at [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5u1zo7g/).

Comment: Yes exactly what I wanted thanks

Answer (score 1):

`var current = 0;`

When you click prev or next u will -5 or +5 to `current` You will hide all of li elements in `.hours-list` element

`$( '.hours-list' ).children().hide();`

In for loop show those 5 adding to current `i`

`$( '.hours-list' ).children().eq(current + i).show();`

Answer (score 1):

I have used some times the [Jquery Quick Pagination plugin](https://github.com/sdeering/jquery-quick-pagination)

It is very simple and easy. You can use it like that:

```
$("ul.hours-list").quickPagination({pagerLocation:"both",pageSize:"3"});
```

Hope it helps!